# How to send data from one web service to another?

Tags: java, web-services

I have two Java web services deployed on Glassfish server, both inside the same web application. What is the easiest way to send an authorisation token (10 digit number) from one web service to another?

Thanks.

Comment: If they're in the same webapp, why do you need to send anything? They share the same memory and have access to the same objects.

Comment: So you are saying if the web service one received token, web service 2 has automatically access to this token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on what you mean by *send*.

I **assume** that you just mean that you want to allow web service #2 to have access to the token generated by web service #1?

There are a few options here, but a couple that jump to mind are:

- store the token in a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) backed [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This will be available application wide.
- store the token in a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) under the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) via the [set/getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) methods. You should be able to access the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) via the [WebServiceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html) in web service #1 and #2 by doing something like: `webServiceContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);`

These assume that you can key into the token somehow (via a user id or something).

Additionally, this doesn't cover the duration for which the auth' token is considered valid and whether it should be valid when the app' is stopped/started/redeployed. Above also doesn't consider load balancing or anything funky like that; it's assuming that you're running a single Glassfish instance.